# SceneKit Error: array for material property contents must have 6 elements

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm getting this error when trying to add color to my shapeNode in SceneKit:
[SceneKit] Error: array for material property contents must have 6 elements

```
    let shape = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
    let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    sphereMaterial.fresnelExponent = 1.0
    sphereMaterial.shininess  = 1.0
    sphereMaterial.transparency = 1.0
    sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor.green]
    shape.materials = [sphereMaterial]
```

When I change it to this, I get this error [SceneKit] Error: Cannot build cubemap from array of images because image at index 0 is NULL:

```
sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor.green,UIColor.green,UIColor.green,UIColor.green,UIColor.green,UIColor.green]
```

I'm running this on the Beta 9.6, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct syntax to assign a color to a material property would be

```
sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
```